# How do you add your queried datatable results into a new datatable

Tags: windows, vb.net, datatable, .net-5

Can someone please help me fill my queried results into the existing datatable or a new datatable

```html
        ''dt is filled with data from a csv file.

        Dim dataRows As DataRow() = dt.Select("[Calendar year TEXT] = '2020'")

        dt.Clear() 'Clear the datatable 
        dt.Rows.Add(dataRows) 'Add the result to the existing datatable or a new databletable if possible ?
```

Comment: Adding the rows to the existing `DataTable` makes no sense because those rows are already in that table. You certainly could create a new `DataTable` but there's probably no point. You can probably use the results you already from calling `Select` or just use the existing `DataTable` and filter it. What is it that you actually want to do with the data? Understanding that will indicate the best course of action, which may or may not be a new `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Your dt.select will return an array of Datarow pointing to the rows in the datatable dt.  Your dt.clear then clears the datatable and so will empty the dataRows array leaving you nothing left.

I'm not clear exactly what you are trying to do.  I'm guessing you have a table that you want to filter and then discard all rows that don't match, leaving you a datatable to work with.

If so, here's a few options:

1. Work with the datarow array directly rather than the datatable.  Is there really any need to convert the rows back to a datatable?
2. Create a new datatable to add the rows to, but don't clear the original table:

   ```
    Dim dt As New DataTable ' Assume this is your populated table
    Dim dataRows As DataRow() = dt.Select("[Calendar year TEXT] = '2020'")
    Dim dtResults As DataTable = dt.Clone()
    For Each row As DataRow In dr
        dtResults.ImportRow(row)
    Next
   ```

bare in mind any changes you make to the rows in dtResults will also affect the rows in dt as they both contain the same data

3. Depending on the size of your table and whether or not you really want to discard non matching rows, you could just remove all rows that don't match then work with the result:

   ```
    Dim i As Integer = dt.Rows.Count - 1
    While i >= 0
        If dt(i).Item("Calendar") <> "Your test here" Then dt.Rows.Remove(dt(i))
        i -= 1
    End While
   ```

Comment: I have tried the code on point 2 but it keeps giving me exception of : "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table". I have also debugged both datatables and they contain the same columns.

Comment: Your point 3 is a good workaround if you don't need the original datatable intact.

Comment: @Abdul-HadiBhat - you're right, sorry.  I've updated code on point 2 so it should now work

Answer (score 0):

So I've figured it out.
The reason I need a new DataTable is that I need to use it again in its original form later.
I could not attach the DataRow collection to my display control which is why I needed a new DataTable with the filtered results.

```
Private Function FilterDataTable(ByVal strQuery As String, ByVal dtRaw As DataTable)

    Dim dataRows As DataRow() = dtRaw.Select(strQuery)

    Dim dtFiltered As DataTable
    dtFiltered = dtRaw.Clone() 'This is very important.

    For Each drow As DataRow In dataRows
        dtFiltered.ImportRow(drow) 'Add each filtered row to new DataTable.
    Next

    Return dtFiltered
```

End Function